# Reputation suddenly reduced: got no reason

Tags: support, reputation

I had a reputation of 126. However, it got reduced to 124 due to a negative vote on an answer.

Now I see it has become 116, though I could find no negative vote in my activity page.

Can the moderators, or the ones with greater reputation take a look and explain how this happened?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You deleted one of your [questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321644/2451).

Comment: So, how much does the reputation come down for that?

Comment: Offtopic suggestion: all capital nicks can look often not the best, please consider switching to simply "Wrichik Basu".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You deleted one of your [questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/321644/2451), which has $2$ upvotes and $1$ downvote, thereby removing $2\times 5+1\times(-2)=8$ [reputation pts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/149663/wrichik-basu?tab=reputation&sort=time).

Comment: How can I, at my current reputation,  view the **number** of up and down votes other than the one shown publicly?

Comment: [Try this link](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/149663/wrichik-basu?tab=reputation&sort=time).

Comment: Got it Thank you